# Como pegar uma informacão específica dentro de um Json com Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
{
"pair": "BTCBRL",
"bids": [
    [2257.89, 0.20752212, 90852987],
    [2257.88, 1.01201126, 90800395],
    [2249.98, 0.05052466, 90806289]
],
"asks": [
    [2272.14, 2.3648572, 90803493],
    [2279.63, 0.08722052, 90840584],
    [2279.75, 0.04118941, 90823262]
]
}
```

Tenho em meu código uma funcão que retorna esse JSON, gostaria de pegar a apenas os primeiros valores do bids e do asks, ou seja, os valores (2257.89, 2257.88, entre outros), como proceder?

No caso, esse JSON chama orderbook, logo se eu pegar orderbook.bids, ele retorna dessa maneira:

```
[
[2257.89, 0.20752212, 90852987],
[2257.88, 1.01201126, 90800395],
[2249.98, 0.05052466, 90806289]
],
```

mas na verdade quero apenas os valores 2257.89, 2257.88 e 2249.98!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar [Array#Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para mapear somente o primeiro item de cada *array*:

```js
var obj = {
  "pair": "BTCBRL",
  "bids": [
    [2257.89, 0.20752212, 90852987],
    [2257.88, 1.01201126, 90800395],
    [2249.98, 0.05052466, 90806289]
  ],
  "asks": [
    [2272.14, 2.3648572, 90803493],
    [2279.63, 0.08722052, 90840584],
    [2279.75, 0.04118941, 90823262]
  ]
};

var novoObj = Object.assign({}, obj);

['bids', 'asks'].forEach(function(item,i) {
  novoObj[item] = novoObj[item].map(a => a[0]);
});

console.log(novoObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100%!important
}
```